# Не могу связать PHP-FPM контейнер с Apache

Tags: docker, docker-compose

У меня есть вот такой файл `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
    apache:
        build: ./httpd
        container_name: apache
        ports:
          - "8080:80"
        volumes:
          - D:/Docker/serv:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
        links:
          - php
      
    php:
        build: ./php
        container_name: php
        volumes:
          - D:/Docker/serv:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

`Dockerfile` PHP:

```
FROM php:8.0.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    wget \
    git \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
libpng-dev \
libonig-dev \
libzip-dev \
libmcrypt-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd 
    
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

`Dockerfile` Apache:

```
FROM httpd
RUN sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
RUN sed -i '/LoadModule rewrite_module/s/^#//g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

При запуске оба контейнера работают, но PHP-код грузится как обычный текст, на всех форумах пишут лишь про использование одного volum'а двумя контейнерами, что я и сделал, может я еще что-то упустил?

P.S. Знаю, что есть уже готовый официальный образ `php:8.0.1-apache`, но мне интересно собрать сервер именно этим путем.

Comment: Я не проверял, но что-то подозреваю, что Apache ещё нужно перенастроить на запуск php-кода

Comment: links выкидывайте, уже 2021 год как ни как. 

Про главное, а вы как представляете связывать php-fpm и apache ? Я прям даже не задаю вопрос зачем вам apache вообще, т.к. это не тема обсуждения, однако же должно быть понимание про взаимодействие ? 

Потрудитесь, почитайте.